# error: ‘Board::Board’ names the constructor, not the type Board::Board; C++

Tags: c++

All right so here is the code where the error is,

Board::Board {

}

so, what makes this not compile?

Comment: Try with a `(` after the 2nd "d". I let you figure out the remaining 50%.

Comment: ***so, what makes this not compile?*** It does not look like a function definition to me.

Comment: What were you trying to do there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, methods and functions have the following syntax:

```
<return-type> <class-name> :: <method-name> ( <arguments> ) { <statements> }
```

Constructors don't have a return type.

Other than that, how does your function definition match the syntax or does it?

Hint:

```
Board::Board()
{
}
```

*Note:  C++ is picky about its symbol characters.  The ( is different than {.*

Comment: It worked but as soon as I recompiled this it had two errors ' undifined reference to "Class name"'